# Utilizing the Dependency-Graph of pip

Tags: python, graph, dependencies, pip

I want to write a visualization of the Dependency-Graph of all python-packages installed with pip. My problem is that the code is poorly documented, and im unable to find where the Graph is stored in the source Code.

I hope someone has enough knowledge about pip-sourcecode to help me out.

Also im new to python and am not sure if i should just make my adjustments in the existing source-code, or write a module for it, although im leaning more towards the latter.

// edit: I can get all installed modules via pip freeze, but that givbes me only one list without the dependencies. So i have to find a way to extract the dependencies from that list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres what i found during my search:

Pip doesn't use a Dependency-graph at all internally. (As of version 1.3.X)

So one solution is to do the following:

You can install setuptools, if you havent allready. It brings a module named pkg_resources.
This module has all the tools, to see all installed modules (not only the ones installed with pip) in your desired dists-directory. You can then read out the metadata (including requirements/dependencies) with methods that are as well included in pkg_resources.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its code is quite unreadable if you're not used to it. I don't recall something like that and I would not use it. You may find yourself better suited with `distlib`, which has a module just for that: https://distlib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/depgraph.html

Comment: That helps indeed. The only problem there is, that distlib is not working properly. And Distutils 2 is out of sync with its doc too.

Comment: To put it in better terms, distlib and distutils2 are both abandoned as it seems.

Comment: Nope, distlib is not at all abandoned. On the repository page you can see that there is indeed daily activity. What do you mean when you say it is not working properly? Can you make an example?

Comment: The Example that you linked doesnt work properly. The one with distlib.database. Apparently theres no such module in the package. It would have been nice for my purpose.

Comment: Well, there is. I don't know what you are doing but you may be doing it wrong. Here it is: https://bitbucket.org/vinay.sajip/distlib/src/3885102d03a23e9b7c5fd5c78cb98a7d37d80bed/distlib/database.py?at=default